# Можно ли в шаблонах Django сделать множественный выбор как в админке?

Tags: django, django-admin

Всем привет, реализовываю форму добавления заказа.

Суть в том, что при создании заказа мы добавляем в него любые материалы, а потом сохраняем. Связь Заказ-Материал many-to-many. Получается, что там должно быть 2 джанго формы, фину из которых потом надо обработать во view.

В шаблоне с этой формой должна быть табличка с множественным выбором, похожая на таблицу из админки. Можно ли такую реализовать в шаблоне с формой?

[image: Таблица из админки]

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно, смотрите в сторону `Fieldset`, `model_fieldset_factory`, смиритесь, что нужно будет реализовывать JS логику.

Искать примерно [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet)

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду копать :)